# Dynamic array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, multidimensional-array, new-operator

I want to create arrays dynamically within the for loop. I have something like bellow:

```
for (int i = 0; i < line; i++){

complex* in[i] = new complex[8];

}
```

complex is a user defined data type. Is there any way to do the above operation. I am getting error for that. I want to create few pointers for more than one array (can't say how many arrays I will need) where each pointer will point to a particular array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think you want *pointers*?

Comment: why aren't you using `std::vector` or rather: `std::vector< std::vector< complex>> in`?

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the *actual* problem that you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 4):

If your 'inner' arrays are all 8 elements each, you can use this approach for a dynamically resizable array of `complex` arrays of 8 elements:

```
std::vector<std::array<complex, 8> > c(line);
// new and delete are not needed here
```

You could of course substitute `std::vector` for `std::array` in this case -- `std::array` may not be available depending on the library you're using.

`std::array` is a little more exact than `std::vector` when the element count is invariant. Thus, `std::array` can make a ton of optimizations `std::vector` cannot. How that affects your program may or may not be measurable.

The good thing about this is that the library implementations are well tested, will insulate you from and detect some usage errors.

Comment: I am not allowed to use std::vector

Comment: @skeptic that requirement's unusual for a c++ program these days -- why can't you use a `std::vector`? (i suggest you also add that detail to your question!)

Comment: Sadly, many C++ courses/professors feel the need to disallow using STL treating it as being "too easy". "Write your own dynamic array, son, you will thank me later". Nevermind that everyone did that in the C course before.

Answer (score 0):

The construct `complex *in[i] = ...` does not make sense. You cannot declare the elements of an array one after the other. You have to declare the entire array *before* the loop.

I.e., something like the following

```
complex *in[MAX_LINES];
// or you can allocate in[] dynamically:
// complex *in[] = new (complex*)[line];

for (int i = 0; i < line; i++){
    in[i] = new complex[8];
}
```

Of course, unless you specifically need C-style arrays (for example - for interfacing with C code), it is probably better to use C++ vectors/arrays (as Justin had shown in another answer).

Comment: `std::vector` is perfectly capable of interfacing with C code.

Comment: @Fred: you must have missed the OP comment where he specifically says he cannot use std::vector. Besides, vectors may be reallocated (and thus have their address change) when elements are added. Better to use std::array for fixed arrays. You still lose the benefit of stack allocation, though.

Comment: `std::array` is just a thin wrapper around a C array. No dynamic allocation going on.